# Show windows program icons (.exe) in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, windows, wine

I'm using `wine` to run windows programs on OS X, however it would like to be able to see the icons of the programs.

I remember that I had something that did this on Snow Leopard, but I can't remember what it was and I don't think it is compatible with Lion.

I don't want to do this manually!

Comment: Do you mean you want to show the original .exe icons in the dock? Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Crossover creates "fake apps" that are actually shortcuts to the installed windows app, which lies in some obscure folder and needs to be executed alongside WINE. If you use Crossover I suggest talking to tech support, as it may be a bug with Lion.

Comment: I want it to show the original icon of the exe in Finder, but I don't want to create a fake app or put it in the dock. I don't want to wrap the exe inside an app.

Comment: @Tyilo unfortunately I believe that's how it works. It is quite straight forward to change an icon though, I'm sure there are many questions/answers on here if you need pointers for that.

Comment: @Robin I had some kind of extension that did **exactly** what I want on Snow Leopard. I have forgotten what its name was.